# DAX Month to Date

Tags: dax, dateadd

Need to create measure that gives me one month backwards (Month to Date)
Been trying DateADD but can't figure it out.

Cant use TOTALMTD function

Date table and column formatted like this : 2010-07-01 00:00:00
2010-07-02 00:00:00
2010-07-03 00:00:00
2010-07-04 00:00:00

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

`prev_month = DATEADD(DimDate[Date].[Date],-1,MONTH)`

`date_init` - column with your initial date. Don't forget to put `.[Date]` after it.

Comment: Sorry, I just get a syntax error.
Date table = DimDate
Column=Date

Comment: try `DATEADD(DimDate[Date].[Date],-1,MONTH)`